# ValueError when i compare input values with database object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to compare form input with database value. For example:

There's a input field called password .. and i want to compare the input value with a password inside the database (in case i know the row already (id))

But when i compare it, i got valueerror like this. googling like 2 hours and nothing works. I'm new to django .. I hope someone can help me :D
[image]

Here is my view code

```
id      = modelUser.objects.values('id').filter(username=txtUsername)
checkPassword = modelUser.objects.values('password').filter(username=txtUsername)

if(txtPassword == checkPassword.password):
    return render(request,'success.html')
```

Models.py

```
class modelUser(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would say to read Django documentation on [how to substitute a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) and [How to log an user in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in).

I will repeat myself and emphasize that I **do not** recommend this method, please follow the framework tutorial and learn how to use its full power.

For the sake of learning, that is how you would do it:

views.py:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.shortcuts import render
from core.models import modelUser

def alternative_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            user = modelUser.objects.get(username=username)
            if password == user.password:
                return render(request, 'alternative_success.html')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass

    return render(request, 'alternative_login.html', {})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from core import views

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('alternative/login/', views.alternative_login, name='alternative-login'),
]
```

alternative_login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'core:alternative-login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I've tried this and same thing happened with this error messages:
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Comment: I have updated the answer. For a third time, please learn to use the framework features.